# Docker container can't be reached from another PC

Tags: mysql, docker

I built a mysql docker container.  It seems to work fine, however when I try to connect to it from a computer it wont connect to mysql.  The computer is in the same lan and can connect via ssh so it's not a networking issue.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the ports not being published or binded correctly.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The most likely suspects for your issue are:

1. Your host firewall is set to not allow connections to MySQL (port 3306).  It may be published by docker but you aren't permitting connections from outside the host.
2. Your docker isn't publishing as part of the same network but rather as a sub-network (not likely since you can connect to ssh from the other computer)
3. Your mysql instance is not set up to listen to remote connections.  Check your my.cnf to ensure that it is isn't listening to localhost:3306.

Comment: I meant to say that I'm able to ssh to the server that docker is running on.  Sorry for the confusion.  I disabled the firewall and I can login into the container using my server that's running docker.  My guess is that docker isn't publishing.  How can I verify if it's publishing or not and fix that?

Comment: Can you connect using a mysql client to the docker instance directly from the host machine?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the mysql from the host machine, just not from outside the host machine.

Comment: The host machine's IP is 192.168.0.36 and the containers IP is 172.17.0.2.  If that helps

Comment: Can you tell me the exact command with parameters you use to connect?

Comment: On the host system (which works) mysql -u root -p -h 172.17.0.2

On the remote system which doesn't work I've tried mysql -u root -p -h 172.17.0.2 and mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.036

Comment: Ok that's why.  You are only doing the local publish.  The 172.17.0.x IP range is only visible to the host machine.  When you run your docker image you need to use the `-p` flag to ensure that the ports are mapped to the host machine.  Then you can connect to the mysql using the host IP address. The docs mention it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong.  My container's name is mysql-2.  The container will only start when I type in docker start mysql-2.  Whenever I try to use docker run it says it can't find the image library.  Also, could you give me an example of what my docker run command should look like?  I'm using docker run mysql-2 -p 3306:3306

Comment: try to use mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1.  If you can connect like that then you are ready you are just using the wrong IP to connect to the mysql instance.  You would use the Host IP not the Docker IP

Comment: maybe you have another service running on those ports locally?